# Java - How expensive is a HashMap.get() call?

Tags: java, hashmap

How expensive is a HashMap.get() call?
The Map in question contains hundreds of mappings and I'm looking to be calling .get() anywhere between 60-1200 times a second.

Comment: So ... try it, and see if it meets your needs. See: Premature Optimization. Specifically, the question is not answerable without knowing what the key is, and how it's hashed. That said ... unless you're using your own class as a key with a *horrible* hash function, that's really a trivial amount of requests and each one will be nowhere approaching 1ms.

Comment: HashMap.get() is O(1). It's raw performance depends on how the hashCode() and equals() methods of the key work, but 1200 times a second, for reasonable keys, is not a problem at all. Measure it.

Comment: The key in question is in fact a String - I'm assuming they have very efficient hashCodes() methods.

Comment: If you're concern about java collections performance try [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) specially if you know the type of keys and values beforehand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`HashMap.get()` is on average `O(1)`, which means it's pretty efficient. This efficiency could drop slightly, depending on the number of elements in the HashMap, but still should be pretty efficient.

If you want to achieve good performance, you should pay attention to having hashcode methods of your keys implemented correctly, so objects gets distributed uniformly across the map's buckets.

This is related to how the HashMap works - oversimplifying it a bit.

Every object in Java has a `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods. When you put a value to the HashMap, it would calculate the bucket to which it belongs. This is done based on the `key` passed to the `put(key,value)` method. HashMap uses the value returned by the `hashCode()` method of the key.

If you had only keys returning distinct hash codes (and if you had infinite number of buckets), HashMap could tell exactly which key+value pair lives in which bucket, but it's not the case.

There could be multiple keys returning the same hash code (leading to placing them in the same bucket), therefore when HashMap finds the correct bucket, with more than one element, it will iterate over all keys and use `equals()` to find the one, which was requested. The less, elements in the bucket the faster the check.

Therefore the better the `hashCode()` implementations, the less collisions, the better performance. Of course the more elements you put to the HashMap, the more likely it is that the collision will occur.

Comment: it depends on hashCode function of objects which are saved in hashMap.

Comment: "efficiency could drop slightly, depending on the number of elements". I would argue. Please explain what you mean

Comment: ...and also the number of buckets in question. Typical implementations of HashMap will resize themselves once in a while to regain efficiency, if the number of buckets is much smaller than the number of elements, and that (rare) operation is fairly costly. By passing in an expected size to the HashMap constructor, you can avoid that operation and keep things running very close to `O(1)`.

Comment: I would say it also depends not on the size of hashMap but on load factor.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many collisions you have (Collisions can push its efficiency from O(1) to O(N)) and the implementation of the hashCode() method of whatever objects your hash-set/map/table contains.

You should write a simple benchmark to test if it takes too long.[Denial of Service with String hashCode()](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=750533)

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis()

...Process hashmap gets here

long time = System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
System.out.println("Took "+time+"ms");
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the number of the elements in the map and of their hashcode distribution.
If the hashcodes are uniformely distributed, the complexity for fetching an element is O(1).

Hundreds of elements in an HashMap should not be a big deal on a fairly modern machine, it should be a matter of milliseconds (or less) if there are only a few hashcode collisions.
Just measure to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

[Like most hash table implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Advantages), HashSet operates in *constant* time (O(1)) for *add*, *remove*, and *contains* operations assuming that your objects have a well-behaved hash function. That means that it takes roughly the same amount of time regardless of the size of the hash set.

For the purpose of the above, a "well-behaved" hash function is one that always calculates the same hash, in constant time, given the same input object, and different hash values for different objects (reducing "hash collisions").

Roughly speaking, hash maps work by calculating a hash code very quickly and only checking the hash bucket that *should* contain the relevant element. Because calculating the hash code should be constant time (and very fast in practice), and accessing a bucket should be constant time (and very fast in practice), a HashMap is one of the most efficient map implementations out there.